# How to use test properties in a Java spring boot unit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing

I have the following class that contains two member variables (`cognitoClientId` and `cognitoClientSecret`) -- both of these values are populated by their respective property values in `src/main/resources/application.properties`:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.clientId}")
    private String cognitoClientId;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.clientSecret}")
    private String cognitoClientSecret;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        if(cognitoConfigurationsExist()){
            http
                .csrf()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests(authz -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        } else {
            http.antMatcher("/**");
        }

        return http.build();
    }
    
    private boolean cognitoConfigurationsExist(){
        boolean cognitoConfigurationsExist = !cognitoClientId.isBlank() && !cognitoClientSecret.isBlank();
        return cognitoConfigurationsExist;
    }
}
```

I have a `application-test.properties` file under the `src/test/resources` directory that holds property values to be used by the unit tests.

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.clientId="testClientId"
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.clientSecret="testClientSecret"
```

I also have the following unit test that tests the if/else logic in the aforementioned class:

```java
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WebMvcTest(SendMessageController.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
public class SecurityConfigurationTest {

    @Test
    void securityConfigurationTest() throws Exception {
        SecurityConfiguration securityConfiguration = new SecurityConfiguration();
        HttpSecurity httpSecurityMock = mock(HttpSecurity.class);

        SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain
                = securityConfiguration.filterChain(httpSecurityMock);

        Assert.assertNotNull(securityFilterChain);
    }
}
```

When running my unit test, I get a `NullPointerException` when the `cognitoClientId` and `cognitoClientSecret` try to derive their respective values from the intended property file.

How do I correctly tell my unit test to use the file `src/test/resources/application-test.properties` to derive the property values for these two variables?

Comment: Try to annot your test class with @SpringBootTest

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@ActiveProfiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ActiveProfiles.html) annotation on test classes to load the properties from specific yaml file, for example if you have `application-test.properties` file under `src/test/resources` and add `@ActiveProfiles("test")` to test class it will load the propery values from `application-test.properties`

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WebMvcTest(SendMessageController.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SecurityConfigurationTest
```